# Delphi. Вывод изображений из Access

Tags: delphi

1. Можно ли хранить изображение в access по ссылку ?
2. Если да, то как потом это изображение вывести в Delphi7 через Image?

Comment: 1. Да. 2. Загружаете в память и выводите. Что конкретно пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: Я пробовал через dbimage, сохранял в бд в поле OLE изображение в bmp, но при запуске выдавало ошибку bmp image is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понял, что значит "по ссылку".

Однако, можно и хранить и читать. Ниже пример сохранения в базе и отображения, использующий ADO. Слабал на скорую руку как proof-of-concept.

```
uses
  jpeg;

...

procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  j : TJPEGImage;
  b : TADOBlobStream;

begin
  j := TJPEGImage.Create();
  b := TADOBlobStream.Create( TBlobField( ADOQuery1.FieldByName('IMG') ), bmRead );
  try
    j.LoadFromStream( b );
    Image1.Picture.Assign( j );
  finally
    b.Free();
    j.Free();
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : TFileStream;
  c : TADOCommand;

begin
  s := TFileStream.Create( 'e:\temp\image.jpg', fmOpenRead );
  c := TADOCommand.Create( nil );
  try 
    c.Connection  := ADOConnection1;
    c.CommandText := 'insert into Table1 ( IMG ) values ( :IMG );';
    c.Parameters.ParamByName( 'IMG' ).LoadFromStream( s, ftBlob );
    c.Execute();
  finally
    c.Free();
    s.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

есть 5 методов хранения информации в БД

1) Хранение как объектов OLE.
Недостатки - большой обьем, необходимость установки набора соответствующих приложений.
Достоинство - простота использования
Пример: учебная база "Борей"
В начале используют все. Потом в зависимости от поставленных задач. И от количества и объема рисунков.

2) Хранение в двоичном формате DIB в поле объектов OLE.
Недостатки - большой обьем, необходимость писать дополнительный код для выполнения загрузки рисунков в БД (но код не слишком сложный, есть типовые наработки).
Достоинство - быстрота вывода рисунков.
Используется редко т.к. по сравнению с первым способом объем базы не уменьшается, а сложности при программировании растут.

3) Хранение в сжатом двоичном формате DIB в поле объектов OLE.
Недостатки - необходимо использовать или разрабатывать самому системы архивации данных, дополнительный код.
Достоинство - меньший объем БД по сравнению с двумя первыми способами.
Пример: sd_Foto.zip с использованием библиотеки zlib.dll. или sd_dbFoto3_97.zip
библиотека zlib.dll для Win2000 Pro и WinXP: zlib123dll.zip

4) Хранение файлов в формате JPG и GIF в поле объектов OLE и загрузка их в элемент управления Image (рисунок) через временный файл.
Недостатки - необходимо использовать временный файл для рагрузки рисунка, увеличение времени загрузки рисунка, дополнительный код.
Достоинство - меньший объем БД по сравнению с тремя первыми способами.
Пример: pictures.rar или sd_dbFoto4_97.zip

5) Хранение в базе данных путей к рисункам в формате JPG и GIF и загрузка их в элемент управления Image (рисунок).
Недостатки - необходимо следить за целостностью набора рисунков, увеличение времени загрузки рисунка, дополнительный код.
Достоинство - самый маленький объем БД по сравнению с четырьмя первыми способами. 
Пример: sd_dbFoto5_97.ZIP

для отображения в формате JPG и GIF подойдет например компонент DBImage